# Looking for a common term for “non-circular pipe”

Tags: phrase-request, translation, terminology

In Russia, there's a special term for a pipe that is not circular in its section: "a profiled pipe" (профильная труба). There's even a Wikipedia page for it: [профильная труба](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0). Such pipes come in a wide variety of sizes and usually have an oval, square or rectangular section ("profile" in Russian), but other kinds of sections are possible.

I wonder what is the common cover-all technical term describing "any kind of non-circular pipe".

[image]

Example of usage:

> Pervouralsk New Pipe Plant produces a range of non-circular pipes, including pipes of variable cross-section.

([Also asked on Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10284/looking-for-a-common-term-for-non-circular-pipe))

Comment: This question seems to be off topic since it is very specialized is not about learning English.

Comment: It does seem like it's about a real challenge faced by an English language learner.  Yes, it's a fairly specific question, but we want specific questions here on ELL.

Comment: @snailplane I agree, but this person does not really seem like an English language learner. OP seems fairly proficient.

Comment: @probablyme - I'm just trying to learn further.

Comment: @probablyme I agree with the second part – the OP seems fairly proficient.  He's a fairly proficient English language learner :-)

Comment: Generally speaking, *pipes* carry fluids, so I would say it is tubing or some structural component (my idea anyway from the Wiki page).

Comment: @user3169 - Russian uses a single noun word for 'pipe' and 'tube' - труба (truba /female gender). Russian translators find it hard sometimes to choose between English 'pipe' and 'tube'.

Comment: @probablyme I am a native English speaker, and I have learned a lot on this site :) Don't think of ELL as a 'beginner' site. I always imagine what I would do if I had the same question about a different language. How would you find the name of that sort of pipe in Mandarin and how confident would you be that you were using the word that most native Mandarin speakers would use? It's not the fluency of the asker that is important, it's the question and how useful the answers are likely to be to others.

Comment: +1 to user3169. This is **tube** or **tubing** not pipe. "Square tube" is a term of trade. http://www.metalsdepot.com/products/hrsteel2.phtml?page=sqtube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several shapes of pipes, and their names describe the profile of the cross-section of the tube or pipe.

> **round**

![here][1]
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC11s.jpg

In general, they can be referred to as

> non-circular pipes
> irregular shaped pipes

Given the advances in plastic extrusion and metal 3D printing, the possibilities are only limited by the practicality of  strength.

Some more traditional shapes are

> **oval**

![here][2]
[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXgS3.jpg

> **square**

![here][3]
[3]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy9zm.jpg

> **D-shaped**

![here][4]
[4]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IvIk.jpg

> **hexagonal**

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [bosscdn.com](http://i.bosscdn.com/product/58/d8/66/3967b2490882bade50882efad5.jpg@4e_360w_360h.src%7Cwatermark=2&text=d3d3LmZhc3R1YmVwaXBlLmNvbQ%3D%3D&t=75&color=I0ZGRkZGRg%3D%3D&size=18&p=9))</sub>

Comment: This answer made my day.